# Change text when user changes tab vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to implement a tabbed browser in vb.net. Everything works fine except for one thing. When the user switches between tabs, the text of `textbox1` does not change to the URL of the current tab in view.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim int As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Loading(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs)
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = e.MaximumProgress
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = e.MaximumProgress
    End Sub

    Private Sub Done(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).DocumentTitle
        TextBox1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
        AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
        int = int + 1
            CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        TabControl1.SelectTab(int)
        Browser.Name = "Web Browser"
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
        AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
        AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
        int = int + 1
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    End Sub
```

I tried implementing this code, but it gives me *OutOfRangeException*, and the debugger suggests that the index of `tabcontrol1.selectedtab.controls.item(0)` is not 0

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
        TextBox1.Text = CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is proceduredeclaration Handles in the Subs - Loading and Done? Maybe because of that you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code to the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Button7_Click(Nothing, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    Dim tab As New TabPage("New Page")
    Dim browser As New WebBrowser() With {.Name = "Web Browser", .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}

    AddHandler browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
    AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done

    tab.Controls.Add(browser)

    Me.TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    Me.TabControl1.SelectTab(tab)

    browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in more checks like this:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim TP As TabPage = TabControl1.SelectedTab
    If Not IsNothing(TP) Then
        If TP.Controls.Count > 0 AndAlso TypeOf (TP.Controls.Item(0)) Is WebBrowser Then
            Dim WB As WebBrowser = CType(TP.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser)
            If Not IsNothing(WB.Url) Then
                TextBox1.Text = WB.Url.ToString
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```